# SugarCRM: Automatically assigning inbound emails to cases

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm using SugarCRM CE version 6.5.8 and I have it installed on a Windows machine. I'm trying to use the feature of SugarCRM where you can assign inbound emails to cases automatically and then assign the cases to users in a round-robin way.

I've set up the scheduler correctly and also set up the emails. The system even processed a couple of mails and correctly created cases out of them. Then, all of a sudden, it stopped working. The scheduler pulls new mails for private mail addresses but not for group email addresses.

I have no idea where to look for the problem or what the cause might be. Anyone facing something similar?

Comment: I appreciate that this thread is old, but did you find a solution?